# generalize Select method of LINQ to Entities in EF5

Tags: c#, linq

I have many cross link tables with two link columns linking to parent tables such as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InsuranceDocuments]
(
    [InsuranceDocumentId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InsuranceId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId] [bigint] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonDocuments]
(
    [PersonDocumentId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId] [bigint] NOT NULL
)
```

1) InsuranceId links to Insurances table

2) PersonId links to Persons table

3) DocumentId links to Documents table

On screens like "Person Details" or "Insurance Details" only document information is needed to show
on initial load, so my "Documents List" structure is the same for all cases like that. Documents table
definition I will omit (too big) but it has basic stuff like Path, DocumentCategoryId etc.

Here is my LINQ for Person and Insurance documents:

```
 public IEnumerable<Models.SearchResult.Document> GetInsuranceDocuments(long parentId)
        {

            using (var db = Core.GetDb())
            {

                var items = db.InsuranceDocuments.Where(a => a.InsuranceId == parentId)
                    .Select(a => new Models.SearchResult.Document
                    {
                        CategoryId = a.Document.DocumentCategoryId,
                        TypeId = a.Document.DocumentTypeId,
                        CreateDate = a.CreateDate,
                        Name = (a.Document.DocumentName == null ? a.Document.DocumentPath : a.Document.DocumentName)

                    }).OrderBy(a=>a.Name).ToArray();
                return items;
            }

        }

 public IEnumerable<Models.SearchResult.Document> GetPersonDocuments(long parentId)
        {

            using (var db = Core.GetDb())
            {

                var items = db.PersonDocuments.Where(a => a.PersonId == parentId)
                    .Select(a => new Models.SearchResult.Document
                    {
                        CategoryId = a.Document.DocumentCategoryId,
                        TypeId = a.Document.DocumentTypeId,
                        CreateDate = a.CreateDate,
                        Name = (a.Document.DocumentName == null ? a.Document.DocumentPath : a.Document.DocumentName)

                    }).OrderBy(a=>a.Name).ToArray();
                return items;
            }
    }
```

as you can see Select method is the same for both
and would be nice to generalize that part, need help with that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract method and use it

```
public Models.SearchResult.Document[] GetDocumentsArray(IQueryable<Models.SearchResult.Document> docs)
{
     return docs.Select(a => new Models.SearchResult.Document
                    {
                        CategoryId = a.Document.DocumentCategoryId,
                        TypeId = a.Document.DocumentTypeId,
                        CreateDate = a.CreateDate,
                        Name = (a.Document.DocumentName == null ? a.Document.DocumentPath : a.Document.DocumentName)

                    }).OrderBy(a=>a.Name).ToArray();
}
```

using

```
var items = GetDocumentsArray(db.PersonDocuments.Where(a => a.PersonId == parentId));
```

Comment: yes that is almost it ! only Where returns IQueryable, should be GetDocumentsArray(IQueryable<Models.SearchResult.Document> docs) ? also call should be GetDocumentsArray(db.PersonDocuments.Where(a => a.PersonId == parentId).Select(a => a.Document)) ?

Comment: @vlscanner yes, there should be Iqueryable, but calling won't change

Comment: without changing call to .Select(a => a.Document) compiler complains but relatioship between PersonDocuments and Documents tables I did not cover much in my question, there is 1 to Many link, but this answer works for me, I will mark it as such. Thanks.